# To display a message box as soon as the usb drive is mounted in java

Tags: java, operating-system

i want a message box when an usb drive is detected as we see an autoplay window when an pendrive is detected.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? What difficulties did you encounter?

Comment: with File.listRoots(); we get all the drive and the (usb drives which are mounted ) before executing it and i want to execute the code as the external drive gets mounted
like an listner

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on WatchService from Java 7. It seems like what you need.

Here is a usage example: https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/watching_a_directory_for_changes

And here is the javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html

Comment: Thanks for the help but its for the file on the FILESYSTEM which are mounted i need a listner which pops up as the new media(pen drive) is detected

Comment: i want to display the no of files in the PENDRIVE as soon as it gets MOUNTED on the SYSTEM hence i need an media listner does java have any of the classes which would help me.
please i am running out of time